# PHP sort an array of array

Tags: php, algorithm

I have the folloring array structure:

```
$list = array();
$element1 = array('start' => '10', 'end' => '15');
$element2 = array('start' => '1',  'end' => '5');
$list[] = $element1;
$list[] = $element2;
```

Every element in `start` and `end` are numeric only.

I would like to sort `$list` by `start` values. How can I do that effectivly?

Comment: Is start value meant to be a string or a numeric? It will make a small difference to the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`usort`](http://php.net/usort) with this comparison function:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a['start'] == $b['start']) {
        return $a['end'] - $b['end'];
    } else {
        return $a['start'] - $b['start'];
    }
}
```

With this comparison function the elements are ordered by their *start* value first and then by their *end* value.

Answer (score 4):

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['start'] == $b['start']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['start'] < $b['start']) ? -1 : 1;
}

$list = array();
$element1 = array('start' => '10', 'end' => '15');
$element2 = array('start' => '1',  'end' => '5');
$list[] = $element1;
$list[] = $element2;

usort($list, "cmp");
```

Comment: +1.  Just to elaborate for the person asking the question, this uses PHP's user defined sort referenced here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php